# Dash Websocket with Payload

Tags: websocket, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I try to send to the WebSocket a payload after the connection is already set.

As stated here: [WebSocket](https://www.dash-extensions.com/components/websocket) one can use a callback.

In my case, I used a callback that is being triggered by the `dcc.Interval` like this `dcc.Interval(id='interval-initial-payload', interval=2000, max_intervals=1),`

For testing purposes, I am using the following WebSocket `wss://ws.eodhistoricaldata.com/ws/crypto?api_token=demo` with the payload `{"action": "subscribe", "symbols": "BTC-USD"}`

WebSocket component:

```
WebSocket(id='ws', url='wss://ws.eodhistoricaldata.com/ws/crypto?api_token=demo'),
```

Callback:

```
@app.callback(Output("ws", "send"), [Input('interval-initial-payload', 'n_intervals')])
    def send_message(n_intervals):
        if n_intervals is None:
            return
        return json.dumps({"action": "subscribe", "symbols": "BTC-USD"})
```

This is not the safest way to do it, since the WebSocket connection could always start later.

Is there a better way to implement this?